# Hapi: Error: Cannot set uncompiled validation rules without configuring a validator

Tags: hapi

Here is my Package.json. I was getting error Hapi: **Error: Cannot set uncompiled validation rules without configuring a validator.**

> ```
>     "@hapi/boom": "^9.1.0",
>     "@hapi/hapi": "^19.1.1",
>     "@hapi/inert": "^6.0.1",
>     "@hapi/joi": "^17.1.1",
>     "@hapi/vision": "^6.0.0",
> ```

```
const Hapi = require("@hapi/hapi");
const Joi = require("@hapi/joi")

const server = new Hapi.Server({ host: "localhost", port: 8003 });

server.route({
    method: "GET",
    path: "/helloWorld",
    options: {
        validate: {
            query: {
                name: Joi.string().required()
            }
        }
    },
    handler: async (request, h) => {
        return 'Hapi'
    }
});

server.start();
```

Answer (score 1):

I have Solve by this:
Here is the reference [link](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/4017):

> ```
>         validate: {
>             query: >>>>{
>                 name: Joi.string().required()
>                }<<<
>         }
>     },
> ```

It should be Joi schema not a plain object.

```
  options: {
        validate: {
            query:Joi.object({
                name:Joi.string().required()
                 })
        }
    },
```