# Cannot set uncompiled validation rules without configuring a validator

Tags: node.js

I have downloaded a learning project so it is not my code, but when I want to start it getting this error. I tried to debug a little bit by myself but as I'm new to Nodejs so having a problem here...

```
Error: Cannot set uncompiled validation rules without configuring a validator

    at Object.module.exports.register (/home/antonp/Desktop/pizza-luvrs/routes/index.js:25:10)
    at startServer (/home/antonp/Desktop/pizza-luvrs/index.js:12:10)
```

here is the link for the full project. [Github repo](https://github.com/ryanmurakami/pizza-luvrs)

index.js

```
const Hapi = require('@hapi/hapi')

const plugins = require('./plugins')
const routes = require('./routes')

async function startServer () {
  const server = Hapi.Server({
    port: process.env.PORT || 3000
  })

  await plugins.register(server)
  routes.register(server)

  try {
    await server.start()
    console.log(`Server running at: ${server.info.uri}`)
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`Server could not start. Error: ${err}`)
  }
}

process.on('unhandledRejection', err => {
  console.log(err)
  process.exit()
})

startServer()
```

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/a/61032418/8993539

Comment: I noticed this answer bet can't find relevant code in my project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your issue is due to a [change in hapi](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/4017). Try changing the following code in pizza-luvrs-master/routes/login.post.js

```
validate: {
  payload: {
    username: Joi.string().alphanum().min(3).max(30).required(),
    password: Joi.string().min(3).max(30).required()
  }
}
```

to

```
validate: {
  query:Joi.object({
    username: Joi.string().alphanum().min(3).max(30).required(),
    password: Joi.string().min(3).max(30).required()
  })
}
```

Comment: If I do that, I have an other error: 

`Type 'ObjectSchema<any>' is not assignable to type 'RouteOptionsResponseSchema'.
  Type 'ObjectSchema<any>' is not assignable to type 'SchemaMap'.
    Index signature is missing in type 'ObjectSchema<any>'.`

Comment: That sounds like a Typescript issue... are you using Typescript?

Comment: Yes sorry… I had a real struggle with that and it went kind of obsessional and then I started to post comment all around without specifying anything… I finally fix that by solving a type definition conflict.

Comment: And by taking a few days of break

Comment: @ErnestJones  Could you clarify on the type definition conflict you have resolved? I don't have a few days of break...

Comment: Hi @Distagon Here is the package and version I use from the hapi eco-system and the type definition I use:

- @hapi/boom: 9.1.0,
- @hapi/hapi: 20.0.2,
- @hapi/joi: 17.1.1

- @types/hapi__hapi: 20.0.2,

For what I understand, some package are shipped with there types and some not. Hope it helps